# how to upload and share rich media linkedin API using php

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api, rich-media

I am using linkedin API skd
https://github.com/zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client
for Linkedin In share

I am able to share normal text content successfully on my linkedin account

But don't know how to share Rich media in post?

Please any one help me,
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I added support of image upload in version [0.0.12](https://github.com/zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client/releases/tag/0.0.12).

It appears to me that LinkedIn doesn't allow uploads.
See [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399000/linkedin-rich-media-shares-api-error-not-enough-permissions-to-access-media-res?rq=1). I believe some steps has to be taken by LinkedIn development team or they supposed to disclose eligibility requirements for those kinds of actions.

I assume we have to be LinkedIn partners in order to perform those uploads.

Comment: Thanks a lot zoonman to write back.
I have checked "https://hootsuite.com/" is uploading images.
Would you please suggest that way so we can upload image same way.

Comment: HootSuite is 100% a LinkedIn marketing partner. They might have access to some extra API endpoints (even to private ones). Are they actually uploading Rich Media or they just uploading somewhere and sharing it? For me none of v2 API worked except token obtaining.

Comment: @zoonman is the library available to use with Laravel? If yes, can you please share the docs.
Thanks

Comment: @AmitKhare, it is generic Composer/PHP library. It is compatible with all modern PHP frameworks based on composer. Laravel, Symphony, Lumen should work with it. But you need to write your own integration..